# Integer to byte array in little endian way (generic function)

Tags: c#

I have this method to convert long to little endian byte array

```
public static byte[] UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(ulong value)
{    
    // Value in bytes... in your system's endianness (let's say: little endian)
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

    // If it was big endian, reverse it
    if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes); 

    return bytes;
}
```

My goal is to use it for shorted data types too, like int, short, etc. See here:

```
byte a = 0xAA;
ushort b = 0xEEAA;
uint c = 0xAABBCCDD;
ulong d = 0xAABBCCDDAAAAAABB;
// If you passed short below, you are only interested
// in first two bytes of the array
byte []tmp = DppUtilities.UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(b);
```

This works if my machine is little endian.
Will it also work if it is run on big endian machine? I think yes, but I would like to verify.

Answer (score 3):

You can play a *trick* with a help of `IntPtr` and `Marshal` in order to convert any *struct* (including `byte`, `ushort` and `ulong`):

```
// Disclaimer: the structure will be reversed as a whole, not field by field
public static byte[] ToLEByteArray<T>(T value) where T: struct {
  int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
  byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

  IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

  try {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, p, true);
    Marshal.Copy(p, bytes, 0, size);
  }
  finally {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
  }

  // If it was big endian, reverse it
  if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

  return bytes;
}
```

....

```
  Byte b = 123;
  ushort s = 123;
  ulong l = 123;

  Byte[] result_byte = ToLEByteArray(b);
  Byte[] result_ushort = ToLEByteArray(s);
  Byte[] result_ulong = ToLEByteArray(l);
```

....

```
  int i = 123456; 
  Byte[] result_int = ToLEByteArray(i);
```

**EDIT**: what's wrong with the implementation in the question? (from the comment). 
      Or, restating the question, what is that stuff with `IntPtr`, `Marshal` for?

The main issue of the question's implementation is the initial *conversion* to `ulong`:

```
  // all the arguments will be converted to ulong 
  public static byte[] UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(ulong value)
```

In order to illustrate the problem, imagine, that we have two values

```
Byte  x = 0x12;               // 18
ulong u = 0x0000000000000012; // 18
```

and the expected output is

```
new byte[] {0x12};                      // for a single byte
new byte[] {0x12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // for 8 bytes, i.e. ulong
```

however, the actual output will be

```
new byte[] {0x12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

for *both* `byte` and `ulong`. This misbehaviour can lead to problems if you, say, want to write down numeric values (`byte`, `short`, `ulong` etc.), to a *binary file*, pass them to a *binary stream* etc:

```
  using (Stream stm = ...) {
    ...
    Byte[] buffer = UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(...);

    stm.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length); // <- the (possibly!) erroneous write
    ...
  }
```

Comment: If you have some `struct` with multiple fields, is not you have to reverse each individual field instead of `struct` as whole?

Comment: @PetSerAl: it reverses the struct as *whole*; so the implmentation is *not very useful* for *arbitrary* `struct`

Comment: @quser: in your current implmentation (that's in the question) you *cast* to `ulong` so if actual argument, say, is `Byte` it'll be treated as `ulong` and you'll get *8 items* array instead of 1 *item one*

Comment: Yeah but that is no issue for me, then I will read only the first byte back of the array (I know I passed a byte to it in the first place, right?). Some other issues?

Comment: @quser: technically, you can take the *first item* of the array for `byte`, or, say, first *4 items* for `uint` but it's an *error prone* implementation: you have to do a post-call procedure for each call of the method.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: " post-call procedure" this is not a problem for me, I still have to remember whether I passed short or what. No other problems? other user above is not sure if my code is correct

Comment: " stm.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length); // <- the (possibly!) erroneous write" - there will be no erroneous write if I read correct amount of bytes from the result, isn't it???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92146/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-quser).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing and I tested it.

I can tell you it works 100%. If you want to check it out yourself, you can for example just pretend you need it the other way. So you reverse the byte array and reverse it if it's `IsLittleEndian`.

Your output is always in `LittleEndian` in your method, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like `BitConverter.GetBytes` has different overloads for that, you should do it the same way:

```
public static byte[] UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(ulong value) { ...
public static byte[] UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(int value) { ...
public static byte[] UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(short value) { ...
```

The complier chooses the right overload when using it like you already did:

```
byte []tmp = DppUtilities.UnsignedIntegerToLEByteArray(b);
```

If you try to do this with a single method that try to check the zero bytes, it will produce wrong results:
How to tell if the number `00 00 12 34` should reverse 2 or 4 bytes?

Comment: "If you try to do this with a single method that try to check the zero bytes, it will produce wrong results: How to tell if the number 00 00 12 34 should reverse 2 or 4 bytes?" Can you please explain what you mean here? I tested my function with many possibilities and it works

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you have a single method, and you pass all different types (int, short, ...) to the method using a implicit cast. How will the method know how many bytes it has to reverse?

Comment: It will cast uint to ulong reverse long and give me back array, please try

Comment: What if you pass a low value, say 1, to the method?

Comment: So what it will interpret 1 as long, get array of bytes from it in little endian way, and return me result. Isn't it?

Comment: Reverse ushort `00 01` you will get `01 00`, Reverse uint `00 00 00 01` you get `01 00 00 00`. Those are different results for the same value of 1. Maybe I miss something...

Comment: They should be different. if you have short value 00 01 - and want to write in Little endian way result is: 01 00. If you have uint value 00 00 00 01 and want to write it little endian way result is- 01 00 00 00

Comment: But how will a single method distinguish between both, when there's always a long as method parameter?

Comment: please write down you can try. If I pass 1 as a byte. It will receive 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01. Then it will get little endian representation of this long which is: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - and return this array. I will only read first byte, is it more clear now?